# How to create a transparent container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to make a container transparent like this: [image]

Here's the container code:

```
: Container(child: Column(
    children: [
             Container(child: Text('Address: '), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
             Divider(color: Colors.grey,),
             Container(child: Text('$address'), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
             ],
            ),
   color: Color(0xFF005D6C),
   );
```

If I give **color: Color(0xFF005D6C).withOpacity(0.5)** then, it is just making the color light like this [image]

How can I make the container transparent?

Answer (score 4):

try wrapping it inside the Opacity Widget

```
Opacity(
  opacity: 0.5,
  child: Container(child: Column(
    children: [
             Container(child: Text('Address: '), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
             Divider(color: Colors.grey,),
             Container(child: Text('$address'), alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
             ],
            ),
   color: Color(0xFF005D),
   ),
)
```

Comment: Now the container's background color is not coming.

Comment: do you have some kind of image in the background? because if you just have a white background below, the color will just appear to be lighter

Comment: Currently, I don't have any background image.

Comment: So thats probably the problem... Try adding something to the background and it'll be easier to se if your container got transparent

Comment: I have given white color to the background, So, if I am giving green color to the container with some opacity, it should make the container transparent

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Colors.transparent` + `withOpacity` for `Container`.

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.5),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Text('Address: '),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      ),
      Divider(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      Container(
        child: Text('$address'),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      ),
   ],
),
```